# python ignoring if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, syntax-error

I've been working on a python program where the user plays rock, paper, scissors against the computer.

The user is prompted to enter 0 for paper, 1 for rock, and 2 for scissors. My program would print what each player chose and ideally I wanted it to also say something like "Paper covers rock. You win" but i can't seem to get my if statements to work and also I want my program to print "you chose paper" etc. but instead of the words rock, paper, or scissors it still says 0,1, and 2.

I tried assigning paper = 0. I thought maybe it wasn't working because the numbers weren't strings so I tried adding parentheses paper = "0", but that didn't work either. Also, when I created the variable 'player' I thought I correctly used the string function to turn whatever integer was entered into a string, but maybe there's something I'm not seeing.

Later I tried avoiding assigning paper, rock, and scissors to the integers and instead creating new variables. However, the new variables created within my if statements were declared as undefined so I must have messed it up somehow. I'm confused as to why it doesn't work because someone else wrote a program for the same purpose using if statements to create new variables and his program worked.

Another place I thought there might be an error is how i ended my if statements with elif instead of else so I changed that and got another an incorrect syntax error. I've been reading my textbook and searching the internet so I'm sorry if I've missed something that should be obvious. I'm super, super, super new to programming so my knowledge is very limited. This code has been warping so much today that i can't even remember how it was when it at least was able to finish compiling without running into an error.

As this code is now it runs into an error because player1 is not defined. I'm sorry that this program is such an eye-sore.

```
    import random
    player = input(str("Enter 0 for paper, 1 for rock, and 2 for scissors:" ))
    computer = str(random.randint(0,2))
    if player == 0:
       player1 == "paper"
    elif player == 1:
       player1 == "rock"
    elif player == 2:
       player1 == "scissors"
    elif computer == 0:
       computer1 == "paper"
    elif computer == 1:
       computer1 == "rock"
    elif computer == 2:
       computer1 == "scissors"
    print ("You chose " + player1 , "and the computer chose " , + computer1)
    if player == "paper" and computer == "rock":
       print("Paper covers rock. You win!")
    elif player == "paper" and computer == "scissors":
       print("Scissors cut paper. You lose!")
    elif player == "paper" and computer == "paper":
       print("You both chose paper. It's a draw!")
    elif player == "rock" and computer == "paper":
       print("Paper covers rock. You lose!")
    elif player == "rock" and computer == "rock":
       print("You both chose rock. It's a draw!")
    elif player == "rock" and computer == "scissors":
       print("Rock beats scissors. You win!")
    elif player == "scissors" and computer == "paper":
       print("Scissors cut paper. You win!")
    elif player == "scissors" and computer == "rock":
       print("Rock beats scissors. You lose!")
    elif player == "scissors" and computer == "scissors":
       print("You both chose scissors. It's a draw")
```

UPDATE: After a few errors have been brought to my attention I have fixed a few things and now my code looks like this:

```
    import random

    player = input("Enter 0 for paper, 1 for rock, and 2 for scissors:" )
    computer = random.randint(0,2)

    if player == 0:
       player1 = "paper"
    elif player == 1:
       player1 = "rock"
    elif player == 2:
       player1 = "scissors"

    if computer == 0:
       computer1 = "paper"
    elif computer == 1:
       computer1 = "rock"
    elif computer == 2:
       computer1 = "scissors"

    print ("You chose " + player1 , "and the computer chose " + computer1)

    if player1 == "paper" and computer1 == "rock":
       print("Paper covers rock. You win!")
    elif player1 == "paper" and computer1 == "scissors":
       print("Scissors cut paper. You lose!")
    elif player1 == "paper" and computer1 == "paper":
       print("You both chose paper. It's a draw!")
    elif player1 == "rock" and computer1 == "paper":
       print("Paper covers rock. You lose!")
    elif player1 == "rock" and computer1 == "rock":
       print("You both chose rock. It's a draw!")
    elif player1 == "rock" and computer1 == "scissors":
       print("Rock beats scissors. You win!")
    elif player1 == "scissors" and computer1 == "paper":
       print("Scissors cut paper. You win!")
    elif player1 == "scissors" and computer1 == "rock":
       print("Rock beats scissors. You lose!")
    elif player1 == "scissors" and computer1 == "scissors":
       print("You both chose scissors. It's a draw")
```

and I am now getting the error:

```
   NameError: name 'player1' is not defined
```

Comment: Python is not ignoring anything. It is simply doing what you are telling it! You are using the equality comparison operator, `==`, where you should be using `=` to assign a value to a variable. Otherwise the code is fine, despite being incredibly awkward in its construction.

Comment: Why do I remember seeing exactly this quite some time ago?

Comment: You should be able to fix the most basic syntax errors before posting updates to this question. The reason you're getting the new error is because you have an extra opening parenthesis  `(` on the preceding line.

Comment: As a side note, you should learn how to use the debugger, or how to insert `print` calls, or how to use an interactive visualizer like [PythonTutor's](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html), so you can see what's going on at each step along the way, and figure out where it's going off-track, instead of trying to figure it out by looking at the whole program from above and guess what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Alright, I'll be sure to study how to do those as soon as I can, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your updated version:

```
player = input("Enter 0 for paper, 1 for rock, and 2 for scissors:" )
computer = random.randint(0,2)
if player == "0":
   player1 = "paper"
elif player == "1":
  player1 = "rock"
elif player == "2":
  player1 = "scissors"
elif computer == "0":
   computer1 = "paper"
elif computer == "1":
   computer1 = "rock"
elif computer == "2":
   computer1 = "scissors"
```

There are (at least) two problems that cause `computer1` to never get defined.

First, `elif` means "else if"—in other words, if `player` equals any of `"0"`, `"1"`, or `"2"`, none of these `computer` tests are even going to happen.

Second, you've defined `computer` as an integer—either `0`, `1`, or `2`. There's no way that a number can be equal to a string, so all of your comparisons are going to be false.

To fix these two problems—which will probably not be all of the problems in your code, just the two problems that lead to this `NameError`—you need this:

```
if player == "0":
   player1 = "paper"
elif player == "1":
  player1 = "rock"
elif player == "2":
  player1 = "scissors"
else:
  print "player is", player, "rather than a string for 0, 1, or 2!"

if computer == 0: # NOTE: not elif, and not "0"
   computer1 = "paper"
elif computer == 1:
   computer1 = "rock"
elif computer == 2:
   computer1 = "scissors"
else:
   print "computer is", computer, "instead of 0, 1, or 2!"
```

---

However, a much better way to do this is to use consistent types instead of randomly mixing numbers and strings, and to use a list or dict instead of a long chain of `if` statements. For example:

```
prs = ["paper", "rock", "scissors"]
player = int(input("Enter 0 for paper, 1 for rock, and 2 for scissors:"))
computer = random.randint(0, 2)
player1 = prs[player]
computer1 = prs[computer]
```

Now, besides avoiding a lot of repetition, you're also ensuring that any problems show up as soon as possible—if the user types `spam` or `76` you'll get an exception telling you that that `'spam'` can't be turned into a number, or that `76` isn't a valid index, immediately, rather than getting a `NameError` about `player1` or `computer1` 20 lines later.

Comment: I really like your use of prs = ["paper", "rock", "scissors"] which I'm assuming uses a list/dict. I haven't read about this yet in my textbook. I'd like to use this in the program I'm working on, but I was hoping to find a solution using only what my class has studied thus far. I fixed my elif to if and removed the quotation marks, I just need to update my post now so it shows.

Comment: @xNx: You're right, `prs` is a list. I suppose that's one reason to ask you to do this problem now. Having to repeat yourself 3 times is just annoying enough so that next week, when you learn about lists, you'll say, "Aha, that would have made last week's problem so much simpler!" instead of "Why do I want that?"

Answer (score 5):

Use `==` for comparisons and `=` for assignments:

```
if player == 0:
   player1 = "paper"
....
```

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry that I missed that! Thank you for pointing it out to me. I fixed that and then noticed that I failed to label player1 and computer1 in my lower if statement so I fixed that too. However, I'm still running into the error saying player1 is undefined.

Comment: Sadly your code is a little bit messed up, but start with correcting your `if`-statements to this: `if player == "0":` and so on... Since `player` is a string you got from `input()` and not an integer. I bet you're facing the next error soon but let's solve it bit by bit.

Comment: Ok, I added the quotationmarks to if player == "0" and just found the extra parenthesis in front of random. Now I'm getting the error that computer1 isn't defined.

Comment: Do it this way: `computer = random.randint(0, 2)` and then `elif computer == 0: ...` The problem is that you can't compare integers and strings, so variables that should be compared have to be of the same type (in this case they are integers).

Comment: Ok, I believe I've corrected those issues now. Now I just need to figure out why computer1 isn't defined. Someone suggested a great way to write this program using list/dict, but I was hoping to find a way to do this program using only what my class has studied thus far.

Comment: You're almost there! Now `player1` is undefined because `player = input(...)` gives you a string but you are comparing `player` with an integer (`if player == 0`). To fix this either change `input(...)` to this: `player = str(input(...))` OR change your `player`-if-statements (only the ones starting with `if player == ...`!) to this: `if player == "0": ...`

Comment: I was so shocked at how well my program worked that I choked a little on what I was eating! Thank-you very much. Honestly, I've been working at this for hours. I wish I'd found this site sooner. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comments and as pointed out in other answers, you have at least two problems:

1. You're using the `==` equality operator instead of `=` which introduces an assignment statement, so you're not setting the values of the `player1` or `computer1` variables at all.
2. You're converting integers to strings for no particular reason, and then comparing these strings to integers. `str(x) == int(x)` will **always** be `False`; unlike Perl or PHP, Python will not implicitly cast strings to numbers for comparisons with numeric types.

Your code can be simplified considerably. There is no need to have a separate `if` statement for every set of possibilities. You can use a `list` or `dict` to store the correspondence between the names of the throws ("paper", "rock", "scissor") and their numerical values, and then take advantage of the natural symmetry of the game. Here's my rendition of it:

```
import random

throws = ["paper","rock","scissors"]

player = None
while player not in throws:
    player = input("Enter your throw (%s): " % ', '.join(throws))
player = throws.index(player)

computer = random.randint(0,2)

print ("You chose %s and the computer chose %s" % (throws[player], throws[computer]))
outcome = (player-computer)%3
if outcome==0:
    print("You both chose %s. It's a draw!" % throws[player])
elif outcome==1:
    print("%s beats %s. You lose!" % (throws[computer].title(), throws[player]))
elif outcome==2:
    print("%s beats %s. You win!" % (throws[player].title(), throws[computer]))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've been instructed to use 0,1, and 2 and to then convert them into paper, rock, and scissors by my professor. I wouldn't normally choose to do this in such a round about way. Also, I haven't worked with list or dict yet. Thank you though for your suggestions. I'll study list and dict.

Comment: My code **also** converts between the numerical values and the strings; it simply uses `list.index` as a means to accomplish this. You could easily "reverse" my formulation so that it asks for a number as input, and converts the number to a string, rather than the other way around.